# Refresh a view when the children of an object are changed in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am working on a CoreData application with two entities MyList and MyListItem. MyList can have many MyListItem (one to many). When the app is launched, I can see all the lists. I can tap on a list to go to the list items. On that screen, I tap a button to add an item to the selected list. After, adding the item when I go back to the all lists screen I cannot see the number of items reflected in the count. The reason is that MyListsView is not rendered again since the number of lists have not changed.

The complete code is shown below:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

extension MyList {
    
    static var all: NSFetchRequest<MyList> {
        let request = MyList.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = []
        return request
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    let myList: MyList
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail View")
            Button("Add List Item") {
                
                let myListP = viewContext.object(with: myList.objectID) as! MyList
                
                let myListItem = MyListItem(context: viewContext)
                myListItem.name = randomString()
                myListItem.myList = myListP
                
                try? viewContext.save()
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func randomString(length: Int = 8) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
    }
}

class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var myLists: [MyList] = []
    
    private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<MyList>
    private(set) var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    override init() {
        self.context = CoreDataManager.shared.context
        
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: MyList.all, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        super.init()
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            guard let myLists = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects else { return }
            self.myLists = myLists
            
        }  catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewModel: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        guard let myLists = controller.fetchedObjects as? [MyList] else { return }
        self.myLists = myLists
    }
}

struct MyListsView: View {
    
    let myLists: [MyList]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(myLists) { myList in
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(myList: myList)
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(myList.name ?? "")
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("\((myList.items ?? []).count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
               
                // when adding an item to the list the MyListView view is
                // not re-rendered
                MyListsView(myLists: vm.myLists)
                    
                Button("Change List") {
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func randomString(length: Int = 8) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
    }
}
```

Inside ContentView there is a view called "MyListsView". That view is not rendered when the items are added. Since, according to that view nothing changed since the number of lists are still the same.

How do you solve this problem?

UPDATE:

What happens if I add one more level of views like for ListCellView as shown below:

```
struct MyListCellView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: ListCellViewModel
    
    init(vm: ListCellViewModel) {
        _vm = StateObject(wrappedValue: vm)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(vm.name)
            Spacer()
            
            Text("\((vm.items).count)")
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ListCellViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let myList: MyList
    
    init(myList: MyList) {
        self.myList = myList
        self.name = myList.name ?? ""
        self.items = myList.items!.allObjects as! [MyListItem]
        print(self.items.count)
    }
    
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var items: [MyListItem] = []
}

struct MyListsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    init(vm: ViewModel) {
        _vm = StateObject(wrappedValue: vm)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        List(vm.myLists) { myList in
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(myList: myList)
            } label: {
                MyListCellView(vm: ListCellViewModel(myList: myList))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the count is again not being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ViewModel` is an `ObserveableObject`, but you are not observing it in `MyListsView`. When you initialized `MyListsView`, you set a let constant. Of course that won't update. Do this instead:

```
struct MyListsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.vm = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(vm.myLists) { myList in
            NavigationLink {
                DetailView(myList: myList)
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(myList.name ?? "")
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("\((myList.items ?? []).count)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `@Published` in `ViewModel` will cause `MyListView` to change when it does, and that includes adding a related entity.

Comment: But MyListsView does not know anything about the ViewModel. All it knows is that someone will pass an array of MyList items and then it will display. I don't want to put ViewModel inside the MyListsView. This causes a dependency on the ViewModel and make MyListView not reusable.

Comment: This is MVVM architecture. If `ViewModel` is not the view model for `MyListsView`, write one. But the whole point is for a view model to contain the logic and to update your view. Otherwise, you are combining view and view model into the view. But unless you are observing your source of truth for the view, your view will not change when it does.

Comment: But that completely breaks the reusablility of the view. The parent is supposed to get data and pass it down to the children.

Answer (score -1):

We don't need MVVM in SwiftUI, the View data structs already fill that role and property wrappers make them behave like objects giving best of both worlds. In your case use the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper for the list and `@ObservedObject` for the detail and body will be called on any changes to the model data. Examine the code in the app template in Xcode with Core Data checked. It looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(item: item)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }
...
struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
```

Comment: who said we don't use MVVM in swiftui? I see a lot of MVVM projects in swiftui.